# WndProc weird behaviour on Windows 8.1: only works if dummy printf is called

Tags: c, windows, winapi

> ***UPDATE:*** @JonathanPotter solved my problem on a comment (see below). Apparently I should have called `DefWindowProc` on `WndProc`. If I call it instead of the dummy `printf`, everything works. But I'll keep the question open because I'm still curious to know why the `printf` itself also made it work in the first place.

I'm writing a program that does something when the notebook lid is opened/closed. There is an invisible window that monitors `WM_POWERBROADCAST` messages and treats them properly. Also there is a console (for debugging purposes).

The program works fine on Windows 10, and then I went to test it on another machine running Windows 8.1, but the `WM_POWERBROADCAST` message was not being captured by the program.

**The weird thing is:**

- If I add a *dummy* `printf` to the beggining of `WndProc`, **the message is received**.

I've prepared a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), in case anyone would like to try to reproduce it (below). Notice there is a `printf` commented at the beggining of `WndProc`.

## Scenario 1: `printf` line remains commented

If I run the program on Windows 10, here's what I get as soon as it runs (no need to close the lid, just run the program):

```
Power broadcast message received
```

But if I run it on Windows 8.1, I get nothing (even if I close/open the lid).

## Scenario 2: `printf` line is not commented

This is what I get on **both** Windows 10 and 8.1:

```
MSG: 36
MSG: 129
MSG: 131
MSG: 1
MSG: 799
MSG: 536
Power broadcast message received
MSG: 49273
```

(Except for `MSG: 49273`, which didn't appear on Windows 8.1, but that doesn't seem to be relevant).

Why is this happening?

**More info:**

- Both Windows are 64-bits
- Compiler: MinGW 64 5.1.0 (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0)

Here is the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message,
            WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    //printf("MSG: %d\n", message);

    if (message == WM_POWERBROADCAST)
    {
        printf("Power broadcast message received\n");
    }
}

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASS wc;
    memset(&wc, 0, sizeof(WNDCLASS));
    wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WndProc;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"Test";

    RegisterClass(&wc);

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(wc.lpszClassName, NULL,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, NULL,
        hInstance, NULL);

    RegisterPowerSettingNotification(hWnd, &GUID_LIDSWITCH_STATE_CHANGE, 0);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't seem to be calling `DefWndProc`?

Comment: I was not aware of that (newbie on creating a Windows app from scrach). I Googled and found `DefWindowProc`. If I call that instead of the dummy printf, it works. Thanks you very much! :) My problem is solved, but I'm still curious to know why the printf itself also makes it work, so I'll keep the question open.

Comment: Btw, your compiler would have almost certainly given you a warning about the lack of a return value from your `WndProc` function. Don't get into the habit of ignoring warnings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is WndProc returns something and you aren't returning anything. The strange behavior about dummy printf is due to artifact of your printf return is left over in the eax register resulting in it becoming the function return.

When adding the default: return DefWindowProc(...), this satisfies the return for most messages so all of a sudden your WM_POWERBROADCAST starts working.

The most likely explanation for failure is your unilitialized return turned into a failure code for WM_NCCREATE or WM_CREATE so the window didn't get created.